# Diff between times in kernel-space and user-space

Tags: linux, time, linux-kernel

i need to exchange a struct timeval between kernl-space and user-space (through a netlink message) in order to calculate the elapsed time between the creation of the message and the elaboration in userspace. 
i'm using the function `jiffies_to_timeval` in kernel-space; in user-space i call `gettimeofday`...but if i print the number of seconds of both structures i obtain a difference of 200 seconds...i can't figure out the reason for this.

Any ideas?

Thank you all!

Comment: I found a solution...instead of function `jiffies_to_timeval` i used `do_gettimeofday` and now all works...so, what is the difference between the two functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are [several clocks inside of Linux](http://www.fieldses.org/~bfields/kernel/time.txt).  The differences boil down to whether they tick while the machine is suspended, whether they try to track "wall clock time", and how high-resolution they are.

`do_gettimeofday` is probably not what you want to use, since that clock tries to track "wall clock time"; that is, it can actually jump forwards or backwards.  What if someone -- or something (like NTP) -- decided to set the system clock between the two times you read it?

For timing, I would recommend using the POSIX [`clock_gettime`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_gettime.html) function with the `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` clock ID.  (You might have to compile your user-space application with `-lrt`, though.)

I believe `clock_gettime` also exists as a kernel function, although I do not have my kernel sources handy at the moment...

Comment: Thanks Nemo for the reply!You are right about that but seems that there isn't clock_gettime as kernel function :( Maybe is there a similar function?

Comment: Found some online kernel sources.  Looks like these live in `posix_timers.c`.  Try `do_posix_clock_monotonic_gettime` in the kernel. (And let me know if it works so I can update my answer...)

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly...i've a kernel-space user-space interaction in about 100~200 micro secs. Thank you very much Nemo!